# Stop sending file permission and owner info from vsftpd to ftp client

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I have Installed vsftpd on centos server. When I connect with this ftp server using filezilla client, then all information about file is shown as below
[image]

When I connect to another server that is on client machine then file permission and owner info is not displayed as shown in below picture

[image]

How can I also disable file permission and owner info like in above picture.

Comment: The reason for that difference is most likely that the second server is a Windows server where file permissions are structured in way that they can’t be displayed as UGO bits. I don’t think you can and you probably shouldn’t hide them on Linux FTP server

Comment: @HBruijn, thanks. I installed msftp server on window and found exactly what you said. +1.